# Reading specific number of lines

Tags: c, file

How should I read a specific number of lines in C? Any tips, since I can't seem to find a relevant thread.

I would like to read N lines from a file and N would be argument given by the user.

Up until this point I have been reading files this way: (line by line until NULL)

```
int main(void) {
    char line[50];
    FILE *file;
    file= fopen("filename.txt", "r"); 
    printf("File includes:\n");

    while (fgets(line, 50, file) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a variable to count the number of lines you've read?

Comment: So you want to print lines 1..N?  You need to modify the definition of `main()` so you have access to the command-line arguments.  You need to check that you got given a numeric argument and convert it.  Then count the lines as you read them, stopping when you reach N lines printed.

Comment: I haven't! That's a good idea.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, that's the goal! I'll modify my code accordingly. Thanks for the great tip!

Comment: @rainer Number of lines you've read meaning the number of times you found `\n` and not the number of times you called `fgets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `N` is given by the user, you could just make your loop count up to `N`:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < N && fgets(line, sizeof line, file); ++i) {
    fputs(line, stdout);
}
```